# Prevent duplicate items from being added to a ListBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I have this code for adding selected items from one `ListBox` to another. How can I prevent the user from adding an item twice?  I want the `ListBox` they are adding to `lstBoxToUserProjects` to only contain distinct items with no duplicate entries.

```
protected void btnAddSelectedItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<ListItem> itemsToAdd= new List<ListItem>();

    foreach (ListItem listItem in lstbxFromUserProjects.Items)
    {
        if (listItem.Selected)
            itemsToAdd.Add(listItem);
    }

    foreach (ListItem listItem in itemsToAdd)
    {
        lstBoxToUserProjects.Items.Add(listItem);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:
Here's what I ended up using**

```
protected void btnAddSelectedItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<ListItem> itemsToAdd= new List<ListItem>();

    foreach (ListItem listItem in lstbxFromUserProjects.Items)
    {
        if (listItem.Selected)
            itemsToAdd.Add(listItem);
    }

    foreach (ListItem listItem in itemsToAdd)
    {

        if (!lstBoxToUserProjects.Items.Contains(listItem)) 
        {
            lstBoxToUserProjects.Items.Add(listItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using the Contains method on the List to see if it is already present?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you bind the `lstBoxToUserProjects` list box to a datasource (HashSet) then you could do a simple check to see if the item proposed for selection was already in the destination:

```
foreach(ListItem itemToAdd in itemsToAdd)
{
    if (selectedItems.Contains(itemToAdd)) continue;
    lstBoxToUserProjects.Items.Add(itemToAdd);
}
```

Note I'm proposing a HashSet because then you can do a performant check on the set whereas a List would have to be enumerated to check for a match.

Answer (score 3):

You should just call ListBox.Items.Contains() in an if statement to check if it has already been added.

```
foreach (ListItem listItem in itemsToAdd)
{
    if (!lstBoxToUserProjects.Items.Contains(listItem))
    {
        lstBoxToUserProjects.Items.Add(listItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to adjust the formatting. I'll figure out how to format it properly when I have more time to.

Comment: did this for you this time, for future - just indent at least 4 spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
protected void btnAddSelectedItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lstBoxToUserProjects.Items.AddRange(lstbxFromUserProjects.Items.Where(li => !lstBoxToUserProjects.Items.Contains(li)).ToArray());
}
```

This assumes C# 3.5, at least.

Answer (score 0):

Change `itemsToAdd` from `List` to `HashSet`:

```
HashSet<ListItem> itemsToAdd= new HashSet<ListItem>();

...
itemsToAdd.Add(listItem) // Adds only new items.
```

[Add MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353005.aspx):

> Return Value
>
> Type: System.Boolean true if the element is added to the HashSet(Of T)
>   object; false if the element is already present. (gdoron- and not inserting the element again...)

Comment: I'm not -1'ing your answer, but I think OP actually needs items in `ListBox` to be unique, not only in single adding action.

Comment: @Krizz. **?!?!**. If `Add` won't cause duplication, how would it happen?

Comment: Are you sure `ListBox.ObjectCollection.Add` ensures no duplicates?

Comment: What is `ObjectCollection`? It's not a member of `HashSet`!

Comment: It is a type used to store items for `ListBox`. It is where OP is adding elements finally. Of course, in `HashSet` items will never get duplicated. But `HashSet` will remain to be "per-add-operation". It won't guarantee uniqueness between several "add" operations, because finally its elements are stored in `ObjectCollection`. See last `foreach` of OP.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
_items_Unique = _items.Distinct().ToList();
```

method it's fast then comparing
where _items_Unique and _items are two list

```
List<string> _items_Unique = new List<string>();
List<string> _items = new List<string>();
```