# Getting all the items from the listbox winform

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, listbox

Good day!
I am having troubles on getting all the items, selected or not, from the listbox. Whenever I click the send button, the only items that I could get is the ones I selected (This is the current results of my code below: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvbbb.jpg). What I want is to get all the items from the textbox not just from the selected ones and which is not repeating.

```
private void cmd_send_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
     {
         try
         {
             String pno = textBox4.Text.ToString();
             String path = textBox5.Text.ToString();
             String name = textBox6.Text.ToString();
             String user = textBox7.Text.ToString();
             output.Text += "\n Sent data : " + pno + " " + user + " " + name + " " + path;
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              wait.Abort();
              output.Text += "Error..... " + ex.StackTrace;
          }

          NetworkStream ns = tcpclnt.GetStream();
          String data = "";
          data = "--++" + "  " + textBox4.Text + " " + textBox5.Text + " " + textBox6.Text + " " + textBox7.Text;

          if (ns.CanWrite)
          {
              byte[] bf = new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(data);
              ns.Write(bf, 0, bf.Length);
              ns.Flush();
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to actually access the list box items in your loop.  All you are doing is reading the same text boxes over and over again (one time for each list item)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419905/prevent-duplicate-items-from-being-added-to-a-listbox 
You can follow this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to access all your items from your `listbox`, you have to iterate all of the items and access the value of that `item`. Here's a sample how you can achieve this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        class Process
        {
            public int ProcessId { get; set; }
            public string FilePath { get; set; }
            public string FileName { get; set; }
            public string User { get; set; }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Process p1 = new Process();
            p1.ProcessId = 1;
            p1.FileName = "Tool.exe";
            p1.FilePath = @"C:\Tool.exe";
            p1.User = "User1";

            Process p2 = new Process();
            p2.ProcessId = 2;
            p2.FileName = "Tool2.exe";
            p2.FilePath = @"C:\Tool2.exe";
            p2.User = "User2";

            Process p3 = new Process();
            p3.ProcessId = 3;
            p3.FileName = "Tool3.exe";
            p3.FilePath = @"C:\Tool3.exe";
            p3.User = "User3";


            ListBox listBox = new ListBox();
            listBox.Items.Add(p1);
            listBox.Items.Add(p2);
            listBox.Items.Add(p3);

            for (int i = 0; i < listBox.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                Process p = (Process)listBox.Items[i]; //Access the value of the item
                Console.WriteLine("Process id: {0}", p.ProcessId);
                Console.WriteLine("Process filename: {0}", p.FileName);
                Console.WriteLine("Process file path: {0}", p.FilePath);
                Console.WriteLine("Process user: {0}", p.User);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

We have a sample class `Process` with different properties. Each `Process` is added on `ListBox` which is later accessed inside the loop.