# Catch the values ​in the listbox respectively

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I need a code that when  click on button1 every time 
the items in the listbox are entered into my textbox, respectively.
And I do not know how to write the foreach loop for the listbox
thank you

Comment: What part are you stuck on exactly? Have you added the click event handler to your button? Have you tried looping over your ListBox's Items property?

Comment: The ListBox has an `Items` property.  You loop over that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting all the items from the listbox winform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31779682/getting-all-the-items-from-the-listbox-winform)

Comment: `txt.Text=String.Join(",", lb.Items.Cast<Object>())`

Comment: @Chris I have a text box on the form
I have a button
And a listbox
I want to add the listbox values ​​to my textbox whenever I click on the button
First time item number 1 Second time item number 2 ....
I could not write a code for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The description of your problem has slightly changed based on what you've described in the comments. If you're trying to add items from your `ListBox` one at a time as the buttons are pressed, you're going to have to check the number of items in the list, or keep a sort of counter in your class. In your original question, it sounded like you just wanted to loop through the list and add all the items to the `TextBox` when the button is clicked *once*. Refer to preciousbetine's answer if that's what you need.

If you're looking to do them one at a time, you can do something as simple as:

```
int currentIndex;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    currentIndex = 0;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(currentIndex >= listBox1.Items.Count)
        return;
    textBox1.Text += listBox1.Items[currentIndex++] + "\n";
}
```

You would probably need a decrement counter as well in a different button event handler if you end up removing items from the list.

Comment: thank you
 I figured out what to do
Your code worked fine
Only the pre item should be deleted when the new item is added to the textbox
Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome. I didn't know about the deletion portion, but you sound like you have a handle on that. If you're deleting items as you're adding them to the box you can ignore the whole `currentIndex` part and just always append the first element (top of the list) followed by a newline. Then once you've deleted the item you've added to the `TextBox`, the second item will then become the first. Cheers.